# Stuck in constructor c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I have a **main** function that creates instances of a class **Simulation** within a for loop, and in the constructor of **Simulation**, there is a for loop which creates instances of pointers to **Populations**.

My issue is that from the output, I know that the constructor of **Simulation** finishes pushing back on its vector of **Population*** but it doesn't seem like it really leaves the constructor because the for loop in the main doesn't continue.
Thank you very very much!

Snippet from **main**:

```
std::vector<Simulation> openSimulations ; 
       for(size_t i(0) ; i < n ; ++i)
       {
           std::cout << "Rounds that should be completed : " << n << std::endl ; 
           std::cout << "Stuck 3 !" << std::endl ;
           openSimulations.push_back(Simulation(f, n, t, p, M, m)) ;
           std::cout << "Finished adding!" << std::endl ; 
       }
```

Snippet from **Simulation**

```
Simulation::Simulation(std::vector<double> pInitialFrequencies, int pPopSize, 
        int pGenerationNumber, int pPopulationNumber, bool pMigration,
        double pMigrationProbability )
:myGenerationNumber(pGenerationNumber), migration(pMigration),
    myMigrationProbability(pMigrationProbability)
{
    std::cout << "Stuck 6 !" << std::endl ;
    for(int i(0) ; i < pPopulationNumber ; i++ )
    {
        myPopulations.push_back(new Population(pInitialFrequencies,
            pGenerationNumber, pPopSize,  myMigrationProbability)) ;
        std::cout << "Stuck 7 !" << std::endl ;
    }

    std::cout << "Have exited or loop in Simulation::Simulation!" << std::endl ;

}
```

Here is my output from Terminal :

```
Dimitris-MacBook-Pro:CMakeTemp Dimi$ ./Genomics  -n 5 -f 0.2 -f 0.2 -f 0.6 -T 100 -N 100 -A 3  -r 3
Rounds that should be completed : 5
Stuck 3 !
Stuck 6 !
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Stuck 7 !
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Stuck 7 !
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Stuck 7 !
Have exited or loop in Simulation::Simulation!
Finished adding!
Rounds that should be completed : 5
Stuck 3 !
Stuck 6 !
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Stuck 7 !
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Stuck 7 !
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Inside Population::Population
Finished Adding Initial frequencies to Population's attribute
Stuck 7 !
Have exited or loop in Simulation::Simulation!
```

Comment: Check your copy/move constructors, and use a debugger. If you want help here, you'll need to narrow down your code to a minimal piece that both compiles and reproduces your problem. (You actually have a good chance at solving your issue by trying to create that minimal demo.)

Answer (score -1):

Hello everybody I found the answer to my own problem!

The destructor of **Simulation** was improperly made.

With the destructor like this, it works now :

```
Simulation::~Simulation()
{
    for(auto population: myPopulations)
    {
        population = nullptr ;
        delete population ;
    }
}
```

I'll just leave the question here in case anybody comes across the same problem..

Comment: You realize that you're not deleting anything with that?

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty new to C++, I didn't realize! Could you tell me how to do it correctly? Thanks!